# Meaning of "laugh though you will"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Laugh though you will, all the drug dealers and gang members had one of these long before any police officer I knew did.

What does "laugh though you will" mean here?

Comment: You can read it as *although I know you are going to laugh at this*, or *go ahead and laugh, but*.

Comment: It's just "although you will laugh" with the word order changed to put additional emphasis on both *laugh* and *will*. It's not an uncommon turn of phrase, but of a higher register and a bit old-fashioned. I would advise against trying to use it yourself at this stage.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in this context, laughter is typically a stand-in for scorn or incredulity. So the beginning of the sentence can be read as "You may not want to believe this but..."

Comment: What is it they all had?

Answer (score 2):

"You can laugh if you like, but all the drug dealers…"
"You may find this amusing, but all the drug dealers…"